# Broken easy_install and sudo pip ("El Capitan")

Tags: python-2.7, pip, osx-elcapitan, easy-install

The "easy_install" command provides the following error: 
[easy_install results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qm4Xn.jpg)

The same output results for the command: "sudo pip".

The command "pip" (without sudo) runs correct.

Result of the "which" command is as follows:
[the "which" command result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tW97I.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling pip?

Comment: I have tried to reinstall by the following command: "sudo easy_install pip". The output result is the same with the "easy_install results" presented above.

Comment: Now "easy_install" runs well, but "sudo easy_install" provides the same error. The same with the "pip": command: "pip -V" runs well, but "sudo pip -V" error provided above.